# Update a single variable of a class in an ArrayList of class in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a class Components:

```
public class Components {

    int numberOfNets; 
    String nameOfComp;
    String nameOfCompPart;
    int numOfPin;

    public components(int i, String compName, String partName, int pin) {
        this.numberOfNets = i;
        this.nameOfComp = compName;
        this.nameOfCompPart = partName; 
        this.numOfPin = pin;
    }

}
```

Inside another class I created an arraylist of Components class:

```
List<Components> compList = new ArrayList<Components>();
```

Later in the code, I am adding the elements in List in this way:

```
compList.add(new Components(0,compName,partName,0));
```

See, here `numberOfNets` and `numOfPin` variables in Components class are initiated with 0 values. But these values are getting calculated/incremented in a later part of code and hence I need to update the new values of only these two variables in each list element. Now from [ArrayList doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) I get the idea of updating a list element using its index by `set` operation. But I am confused how to set/update a particular variable of a class in an ArrayList of a class. I need to update only these two mentioned variables, not all of the four variables in Components class. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add getter/setter to your component class so that outer class can update component's members

```
public class Components {

    private int numberOfNets; 
    private String nameOfComp;
    private String nameOfCompPart;
    private int numOfPin;

    public components(int i, String compName, String partName, int pin) {
        setNumberOfNets(i);
        setNameOfComp(compName);
        setNameOfCompPart(partName); 
        setNumOfPin(pin);
    }

    public void setNumberOfNets(int numberOfNets) {
        this.numberOfNets = numberOfNets;
    }

    // Similarly other getter and setters
}
```

You can now modify any data by using following code because get() will return reference to original object so modifying this object will update in ArrayList

```
compList.get(0).setNumberOfNets(newNumberOfNets);
```

Answer (score 3):

Example code.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Components> compList = new ArrayList<Components>();

        compList.add(new Components(0, "compName", "partName", 0));

        System.out.println(compList.get(0).toString());
        
        compList.get(0).numberOfNets = 3;
        compList.get(0).numOfPin = 3;
        
        System.out.println(compList.get(0).toString());     
    }   

}
```

Your class.

```
public class Components {

    int numberOfNets;
    String nameOfComp;
    String nameOfCompPart;
    int numOfPin;

    public Components(int i, String compName, String partName, int pin) {
        this.numberOfNets = i;
        this.nameOfComp = compName;
        this.nameOfCompPart = partName;
        this.numOfPin = pin;
    }

    public String toString() {

        return this.numberOfNets + " " + nameOfComp + " " + nameOfCompPart
            + " " + numOfPin;
    }

}
```

The output:

> 0 compName partName 0
>
> 3 compName partName 3